# Updating JTree nodes background color at runtime

Tags: java, user-interface, swing, jtree

I need to change tree nodes color when business logic updates model, wait 1 second, and then change its color back.

Basically I would like to create similar thing like here [Changing JList row color at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1664924/changing-jlist-row-color-at-runtime), but for JTree.

So I could use a similar technique,but I also wont to change ancestor nodes color, so user could see notification even if not is not expanded.

How can I do it?

Comment: What does "Mógłbym użyć podobnej techniki" mean?

Comment: sorry :(, I was trying to check spelling and make ctr+c + ctr+v on wrong line in google treanslate... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this [Highlight a node's descendants in JTree](http://www.jroller.com/santhosh/entry/highlight_a_node_s_descendants)

You could easily modify it to instead highlight the parent and now you only need to plug in a solution for the timed highlighting like the solution I provided on the other thread. Highlight, timer, unset highlight.

Using [SwingWorker](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html) plus maybe an [Executor](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/index.html?javax/swing/SwingWorker.html) if the updates to the model are frequent and you want some control over the execution of the highlighting threads

Answer (score 2):

First, when the business model is updated, make sure you fire the appropriate tree updated event in your tree model so the JTree will know to update.

Then you'll need to define a TreeCellRenderer that sets the color. When the business model is updated, tell your renderer which nodes to highlight.

However, the trick here is turning the color off. You can define a Thread or better yet an Executor to sleep for 1000 millis then tells the renderer to no longer highlight the nodes, *then* fire the tree update events again so the JTree will repaint appropriately.

Comment: You should not define an arbitrary thread or Executor to fire the tree update event as this should be fired on the Event Dispatch Thread.

Comment: True. Instead use SwingWorker or SwingWorker + Executor

Comment: That could work, or use SwingUtilities.invokeLater() to put the tree update in the UI thread.

Answer (score 0):

It should be improved with SwingWorker to uncolor back after a time:

```
  class RuntimeTreeRender extends DefaultTreeCellRenderer {


    boolean specialColor = false;

    @Override
    public Color getBackgroundNonSelectionColor() {
        if(specialColor) {
            return Color.GREEN;
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }


    @Override
    public Component getTreeCellRendererComponent(JTree tree, Object value, boolean arg2, boolean arg3, boolean arg4, int arg5, boolean arg6) {

        Component c = super.getTreeCellRendererComponent(tree, value, arg2, arg3, arg4, arg5, arg6);

            DefaultMutableTreeNode node = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) value;

                if(YOUR_CONDITION_ON_NODE) { // for exammple : node.getUserObject().toString().contains("a")
                    specialColor = true;
                } else {
                    specialColor = false;
                }

        return c;
    }
```

}