# How would I go about highlighting an item in a JList?

Tags: java, highlight, jlist

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Changing JList row color at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1664924/changing-jlist-row-color-at-runtime)

I have a JList and I want to be able to highlight (change colour of text or something similar)  the selected item. I know there are methods to set which item is selected but can I change the color of the text of that item etc?

Comment: Do `setSelectionBackground()` and `setSelectionForeground()` not do what you need?